# Programming logic best practice - redundant checks

Tags: php, coding-style, logic

I'm creating a large PHP project and I've a trivial doubt about how to proceed.

Assume we got a class `books`, in this class I've the method `ReturnInfo`:

```
function ReturnInfo($id) {
    if( is_numeric($id) ) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='" . $id . "' LIMIT 1;";

        if( $row = $this->DBDrive->ExecuteQuery($query, $FetchResults=TRUE) )   {  
                return $row;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Books - ReturnInfo - id not valid.');          
    }
}
```

Then i have another method `PrintInfo`

```
function PrintInfo($id) {
    print_r( $this->ReturnInfo($id) );
}
```

**Obviously the code sample are just for example and not actual production code.**

In the second method should I check (again) if id is numeric ? Or can I skip it because is already taken care in the first method and if it's not an exception will be thrown?

Till now I always wrote code with redundant checks (no matter if already checked elsewhere i'll check it *also* here)

Is there a best practice? Is just common sense?

Thank you in advance for your kind replies.

Comment: Redunant checks add security in a way that the methods can be reusable without the fear of a security flaw.

in this specific case, the int checking is nothing special and you could just cast it on (int) but for multiple checks consider a "checkBookid" method to handle the validation. calling it twice can sound redundant, but at least if the validation method changes all methods using it will be OK and safe.

Comment: ^ and testing independantly

Comment: i would say it depends on the scope of the method, if it were a private method and i knew that validation was handled outside the method, then i would not do any more validation. However if it were public id say you would have to perform validation from within the method to guarantee the data type

Comment: Though I prefer using prepared statements... Till, `is_numeric` is good enough for sanitizing input for SQL.

Comment: @jtavares The innermost method(s) which actually uses the value does the validity checking. It already protects itself from security vulnerabilities by doing so. If every outer layer is checking as well, that's indeed simply redundant, not more secure.

Comment: `15.2` is also numeric, but not an int (which id probably will be)

Comment: @Kris but cannot facilitate SQL injection either, other than making the method to be certain to return false, lol.

Comment: @Kris true i believe the required function is is_int()

Comment: @deceze thats why that example isnt the best, becouse the printInfo is just 1 line long, but imagine another funcionality comes in to the code and printInfo calls another method that somehow is not secure. that would bring a flaw into the system.

there is no "right" way of doing so but I like my methods double checked.

Comment: @jtavares if print info calls another function and you have not sanitised the input thats bad coding on the developers part. If the developer of the class has a method of validating all input outside of the method calls whats the point of validating it twice? The only sense I see in it is if the method is public and could be called once the object is instanciated and/or extended.

Comment: @jtavares i just wondering if my code will be optimized doing so (i know we're talking about small optimization but still) imagine a stack of methods where the $id is checked (is_int) 5 or 6 times.

Comment: @jtavares Every function that "does something dangerous" with a value needs to validate or sanitize the value itself. You can never rely on the validation happening elsewhere.

Comment: @Kris is_int is better indeed. Thanks

Comment: @deceze that deppends, do you validade your data on your models or on your controlers?

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @jtavares The model/business logic layer must do all the validation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ask yourself what you *gain* by checking in every layer. Is it more security? No, since the function which uses the value for something, which is the only one being vulnerable, does the checking itself.

The only advantage it has is that you can stop invalid values earlier, which executes less code. It doesn't have to go all the way down and back up before you know the value is invalid. This may or may not be a real advantage.

It does create problems though: you have more code. Your code is not DRY anymore. If you change the definition of what makes a "valid" value, you have to change the checks all over the place. Those are much bigger problems.

I'd approach the problem this way: your core business model does the in-detail checking, it is ultimately responsible for making sure the value is valid, and it is the only one doing something "dangerous" with this value. The outer layers (controllers, views) merely pass the value along. With one exception: they may do "rough" data validation. Say your model expects a phone number with specific formatting. You should check this specific rule inside the model. In the view/controller layer you may roughly validate the value as being at least somewhat numeric though. Say, you have a Javascript check. This blocks obviously wrong values from bothering your core app, while still giving you the flexibility to tweak the core validation rule in just one place.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are double-checking the return inside of a loop that is executing many thousands of times in succession you're not even going to *notice* the redundant check. Even so, a type check is a very small operation and will be orders of magnitude faster than the SQL query being used to retrieve the data in your example.

Unless you're *really* pinching CPU cycles for a realtime application you're likely going to enjoy the ass-coverage that the extra check affords you.

That said, your functions should generally be validating their *inputs* as much or more strictly than their outputs, so the only place where you would be writing an extra redundant check like this would be for some inline functionality that requires strict typing/validation.